# DLL import gone wrong? Missing class

Tags: c#, class, dll, unity-game-engine, using

I am trying to ressurect an older project of mine in a newer Unity3D version. This is all well and good, except for a plugin that it was using is messing up.

I am using TouchScript : https://github.com/TouchScript
I updated to the newest version and everything, but i keep getting an error saying:

```
Assets/Scripts/Puzzle/Gesture Usage/PickupScript.cs(149,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `TouchHit' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

This script has the required `Using TouchScript.Hit;` line. And i opened up the DLL to make sure that the class "TouchHit" is there, and it is. However when viewed in monodevelop by going to the DLL itself, it does not show at all. It shows the other classes that are supposed to be there, but not that specific TouchHit class.

I used that class, thus the error. But i am unsure on how to proceed with fixing this. I tried all sorts of import settings but no luck.

Any ideas?

Sincerely,
Smileynator

Answer (score 1):

The classes in question were marked INTERNAL at some point, and documentation did not reflect this until i started looking at the commit regarding this change in feb 2014.

https://github.com/TouchScript/TouchScript/commit/ccb1a6cb44cb444618ca613fe1f8e5b15c076cc3